# How to install a jQueryMobile app project inside smartphones and tablets?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQueryMobile projects are made of only html files ! There may be folders included in the project because the files associated for the css and js are downloaded. So how to install the project package into smartphones and tablets ? And how to launch it when installed in smartphones and tablets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile apps created with HTML/JS/CSS have to be wrapped with something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to be installed like native applications.

More info in [PhoneGap wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap).